# How to set and read multiple values from JSP(select) to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jstl

I need to get multiple values in Java Script from select.

```
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="1">desc1</option>
  <option value="2">desc2</option>
  <option value="3">desc3</option>
  <option value="4">desc4</option>
  <option value="5">desc5</option>
</select>
```

This is populated using JSTL from below model,

```
public class Model implements Serializable{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   String id;
   String desc;
   String date;

   public Model(){};
   public Model(String id, String desc,String date){
      this.id= id;
      this.desc = desc;
      this.date = date;
   }

   public String getId() {
      return id;
   }
   public void setId(String id) {
      this.id = id;
   }
   public String getDesc() {
      return desc;
   }
   public void setDesc(String desc) {
      this.desc = desc;
   }
   public String getDate() {
      return date;
   }
   public void setDate(String date) {
      this.date = date;
   }
}
```

I am using jQuery to check the selected value. But i do not know how can i also read the 'date' value associated for the selected value in jQuery?

Comment: Can you add the date as a custom data attribute on the option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really get the model date via jQuery or JS if it is not accessible by the DOM. To make this work, you can populate the data-date attribute for each of the options and then retrieve them using the the data function.

```js
$('#myselect').change(onChange);
function onChange() {
  var selectedOption = $('#myselect option:selected');
  var date = selectedOption.data("date");
  console.log(date);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
  <option data-date="Feb 10, 1999" value="1">desc1</option>
  <option data-date="Feb 11, 1999" value="2">desc2</option>
  <option data-date="Feb 12, 1999" value="3">desc3</option>
  <option data-date="Feb 13, 1999" value="4">desc4</option>
  <option data-date="Feb 14, 1999" value="5">desc5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is the custom data attributes supported in all browser versions?

Comment: Custom data attribute is not working in IE8. I have tried jQuery and plain javascript, both failed. `var date = document.getElementById('myselect').options[myselect.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-date');`

Comment: So are you not able to run the example above on IE8?

Comment: Yes, I am not able run the example on IE8

Comment: @Vel It should work. I think it maybe that a lot of scripts and Stackoverflow itself it throwing errors when shown in IE8. Try it on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dbup3mLe/

Comment: We aren't supporting IE 8 anymore in our application. Thanks for your inputs!